# JSON WCF Method not allowed

Tags: wcf

I have WCF with contract like that

```
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "UpdateEncounterStatus/{BookingID}/{BookingStatus}")]
        public void UpdateEncounterStatus(string BookingID, string BookingStatus)
```

and I call it using

```
http://localhost:1185/PMAHost/Service.svc/UpdateEncounterStatus/141/sfsa
```

but it give

the web.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type=""/>
          </add>
          <add name="xml">
            <filter type=""/>
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type=""/>
          </add>
          <add name="xml">
            <filter type=""/>
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="XMLService.dll" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type=""/>
          </add>
          <add name="xml">
            <filter type=""/>
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\XMLServiceTrace.svclog"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
           name="xml"
           traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack">
        <filter type=""/>
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <connectionStrings>
```

```
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionStringName="Login"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             applicationName="/"
             requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             passwordFormat="Hashed"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="PMAService.PMA">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="PMAService.IPMA" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultRest">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="64" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you trying to call directly from the browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `UpdateEncounterStatus` method is marked for POST request and when you are trying to issue the request from the browser address bar then you are issuing a GET request so you are getting `405 Method Not Allowed error`. To fix this you have to mark the method with `WebGet` or `WebInvoke(Method="GET")`

**UPDATE**: In your case you are performing an update operation so as per REST you should not change it into GET only POST.

Comment: you mean it will work from application , yes I call stored procedure for update

Comment: using jquery u can easily invoke through POST